# Mac: What is /Users/PortDetect.log?

Tags: macos, security, logging

I have a file called /Users/PortDetect.log on my MacBook Pro, with contents like

```
Wed Nov 25 18:22:42 2009
--  PortDetect started...

Wed Nov 25 18:23:19 2009
--  PortDetect started...
```

Who is making this log file? It is in a rather weird location, so I am assuming that it is not something that is part of the OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search on [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=portdetect.log) or [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=portdetect.log) of that filename returned [this page](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-587469.html) as the first result.  Have you used a mobile Internet card on this computer?  The brand that I'm seeing is T-Mobile Web 'n' Walk.

To uninstall, follow [instructions on T-Mobile's website](http://support.t-mobile.co.uk/help-and-support/index?page=support&cat=WEBNWALK_USB&tab=3&id=GP107).

Comment: Yes, a USB wireless modem (not T-Mobile, though). However, I stopped using that last month. How can I uninstall this PortDetect thing?

Comment: Questions like these are easily answered by searching the web for "uninstall tmobile web n walk mac software". I've added the page I found to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the portdetect.log file by removing two folders in the /Library/StartUpItems Folder. HWNetMgr and HWPortDetect folders were sent to the trash, then I restarted my Mac. Deleting the log file itself will not work because HWPortDetect will replace it automatically.